# MySQL use math and grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

no grouping according to new lat and lon columns, 
why grouped by old columns

```
select 
  CEIL( b.lat) AS lat ,
  CEIL( b.lon)  AS lon, 
  b.lat,
  b.lon,
  Count(*) 
from tur_gozlem a 
inner join geopoints b on a.harita = b.id
group by lat,lon
order by lat,lon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a name collision.  Either use unambiguous aliases or repeat the expressions:

```
select CEIL(gp.lat) AS lat, CEIL(gp.lon) AS lon, Count(*)
from tur_gozlem tg inner join
     geopoints gp
     on tg.harita = gp.id
group by CEIL(gp.lat), CEIL(gp.lon)
order by lat, lon;  -- will correctly refer to aliases
```

Notes:

- You have two columns each with the name `lat` and `lon` in the `SELECT`.  How is the `GROUP BY` supposed to know which to use?
- You have unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  This should generate a compile error when you try to run the query.
- Use meaningful table aliases.  `a` and `b` are meaningless.  Table abbreviations are meaningful.